# Python defining iterators for dictionary comprehension for a class

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I want to check with someone if I defined the iteration function properly. To explain, please consider the following example:

```
x=[{'n':'foo', 'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[2,3,5]}, {'n':'baz','a':[4,5,6], 'b':[7,8,9]},
   {'n':'foo', 'a': [4,3,4], 'b':[1,5,6]}, {'n':'bar','a':[1,2,2], 'b':[2,5,6]}]

quick_dict = {key['n']: [sample['a'] for sample in x if sample['n']==key['n']] for key in x}
```

This works as expected and outputs:

```
{'foo': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 4]], 'baz': [[4, 5, 6]], 'bar': [[1, 2, 2]]}
```

I am trying to do something similar for a class I defined using the `__next__` and `__iter__` methods. The class instance has many functions and attributes but for the purpose of this question, only the attribute `samples` is important because it is a list of dictionaries exactly as in the above example. I defined the methods as follows:

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.itercounter < len(self.samples)-1:
        self.itercounter +=1
        return self.samples[self.itercounter]
    else:
        raise StopIteration

def __iter__(self):
    self.itercounter = -1
    return self
```

This seems to work for list comprehensions, but it fails for dictionary comprehensions.

If I do:

```
quick_dict = {key['Name']: [sample['CM'] for sample in data if sample['Name'] == key['Name']]
              for key in data.samples}
```

then it works because it is directly accessing the list of dictionaries and it knows what to do. On the other hand if I do

```
quick_dict = {key['Name']: [sample['CM'] for sample in data if sample['Name'] == key['Name']]
              for key in data}
```

then it is going through my functions, and it doesn't work. It just returns a dictionary with a single key. Here `'CM'` is just a key like `'a'` in the example.

What am I doing wrong in my definition of `__iter__` and `__next__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second definition of `quick_dict` iterates over `data` with `for sample in data` while already iterating over it with `for key in data`.  However, your `__iter__` and `__next__` implementation uses a single instance attribute to control iteration, meaning that nested iteration over `data` won't work because the second (nested) call to `__iter__` resets the counter.  To support nested iteration, eliminate `__next__` and have `__iter__` return a generator instead:

```
def __iter__(self):
    i = -1
    while i < len(self.samples)-1:
        i += 1
        yield self.samples[i]
```

Comment: @BradSolomon: Yes, but I was trying to match the logic from the OP.

Comment: That works. Thanks! Also thanks for the `yield from self.samples`. Much cleaner!